# updating a javascript object via an input field

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript object that contains the following:

```
tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"], // your tags
```

What i'd like do is populate the object via an input field such as a text box or possibly even via a multi select dropdown, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please remember that SO is not a general help forum, and there are policy articles that explain what is [on topic](/help/on-topic). Generally if you're still in the "I'm thinking of doing X, how would you suggest I start?" stage, then your questions are not yet on-topic for Stackoverflow. Once you've decided on one or more approaches, and wrote code for them, and then got stuck (_and_ attempted to debug yourself, first!), that's the right time to ask on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add an button and append the text entered in your input field to your tags array when the button is clicked.

Example JS code:

```
yourButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let value = yourInput.value;

    if (value) {
        tags.push(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fragezeichen, i should have put more thought into my question, i will repost with a better explanation,